# How to show a form field (input type="text") when i click on a <select> item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

[image]

How to show the form field (input type) in the when I clicked "7th" from the select menu.

Comment: Show us some code before we can help you

Comment: Add `onchange` event handler, check current selected value - show/hide textfield.

Comment: I do this before but it can't work for me...

Comment: @SyedWaqasAhmad We need to see your code, we cant help you without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html code should be like

```
<select id="select">
<option value="6th">6Th</option>
<option value="7th">7Th</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox"/>
```

and by using jQuery show textbox like

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#textbox').hide();      
});

$('select').on('change', function() {
  if(this.value == '7th'){
  $('#textbox').show();      
  }
});
```

Comment: I recommend you add a `style="display: none;"`-attribute to the `input`-tag in your HTML. Otherwise, the HTML will render it, and after that, your JS will hide it again. Better hide it *before* it gets to appear.

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to rely on jquery this is a javascript example.

```
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("example");
    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    dropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
        if(dropdown.value == 7){
            textbox.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            textbox.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="example">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
</select>
<input id="textbox" type="text" style="display:none;">
</body>
```

Comment: Native JavaScript are always the best answers to beginners ! ;-)